# Raise 404 instead of 500 when using an invalid uuid

Tags: python, django, uuid

I have a **uuid** field in my `Document` model

If I get() my model with a bad uuid, I got a error 500.
This line throw an error:

```
x = Document.objects.get(uuid=object_uuid)
```

**Instead of a 500 I want a 404 error**

I wrote this, but I don't want to put my function everywhere it's so redundant (I'm lazy)

```
def is_valid_uuid_or_404(object_uuid):
    try:
        return uuid.UUID(object_uuid)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404("Invalid uuid")

x = Document.objects.get(uuid=is_valid_uuid_or_404(object_uuid)) #Boring
```

Someone has a good idea to make it better ?

### **EDIT 1 :**

I get my object in my admin's `change_view` method, I override the `change_view` to add extra_context, this follows the recommendation of [django](http://djangohttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view)

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url="", extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context["my_field"] = Document.objects.get(uuid=object_id).my_field
    return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: And how do you get this `object_uuid`? If from the url use the `uuid` path converter, if from a form use the `UUIDField`. _Needing_ to handle this error is simply because you don't use proper means to validate your inputs.

Comment: object_uuid comes from the change_view parameter, I edited my question to be more specific @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Oh I see, the model admin is for the model you query for yes? and the uuid is the primary key? I'll edit my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Yes the uuid is my primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to get this object in the model admin simply use the `get_object` method the model admin already has to get the object, this way you won't need to handle the errors and all you would need to handle would be the method returning a `None` since there is no matching object:

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import unquote


def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url="", extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    
    to_field = request.POST.get('_to_field', request.GET.get('_to_field'))
    object = self.get_object(request, unquote(object_id), to_field)
    
    extra_context["my_field"] = object.my_field if object else None
    return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

**General Solution**:

A bad (invalid) uuid will cause this error, and this gives you a 500 response instead of which you want a 404 response. Instead of catching this error, the better thing to do is perform *validation* beforehand. There are few areas where you might have gotten the UUID from, keeping things simple we'll assume you either got it from a url parameter or from a form. Both of these of course have proper ways to validate a UUID.

For a url pattern, you should use the [`uuid` path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), if the passed uuid is not a valid uuid the request won't even be routed to the view and you'll get a 404:

```
path('some-view/<uuid:object_uuid>/', views.some_view),
```

Next for a form you should use a [`UUIDField` [Django-docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#uuidfield) and make use of the forms cleaning and validation:

```
from django import forms


class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    object_uuid = forms.UUIDField()


# In your view
def some_view(request):
    ...
    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        object_uuid = form.cleaned_data['object_uuid']
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because I'm overriding the `change_view` method, I edited my question to be more specific

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, a thousand thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/) and then add a custom method to that

```
from django.db import models

class DocumentManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_uuid(self, uuid, **kwargs):
            
        try:
             return uuid.UUID(object_uuid)
        except ValueError:
            raise Http404("Invalid uuid")
    
        return self.get(uuid=uuid, **kwargs)

class Document(models.Model):
      objects = DocumentManager()


x = Document.objects.get_by_uuid(object_uuid)
```

Comment: This is not going to work because django will give me an ValidationError due to invalid uuid before checking if the document exists

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER - Ah i assumed you were getting an object does not exist error, you could create a custom manager for the class(es) you're using this on

Comment: It's a good idea, but all of my models are using uuid, I don't want to create a custom manager for all of my models

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER - You could always make a base class or mixin that all your classes can inherit from